# Opening Android app from URL does not open the right activity

Tags: android

I have a very strange problem regarding Android `intent-filter` from URL.

In short: I have activity A as MAIN & LAUNCHER and activity B that has intent-filter that allows it to be opened via **href="intent://..."**. Activity B has activity A listed as parent.

If I open the app via clicking the **href**, it opened directly to B (as expected). But then, if I press back (so I am in activity A) and try to open the app from **href** *again*, it opened to activity A instead of B! This is is really strange as activity A does not have any intent filter other than MAIN and LAUNCHER.

What I have right now:

**Manifest containing activity A and activity B:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app">

<activity
            android:name=".AActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<activity
            android:name=".BActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".AActivity">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".AActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="m.something.com"
                    android:path="/somepath"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**The href I used:**

```
href="intent://m.something.com/somepath#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.my.app;S.extra_string=name@domain.com;end"
```

**Activity B code:**

At first, I didn't override the `onOptionsItemSelected`. I thought if I have specified the parent activity in the manifest, then Android (by default) will open Activity A, but when I opened activity B from URL and press up, it closed the app. Therefore, I need to do the following code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setSupportActionBar(...);
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (isTaskRoot()) {
                   Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
                   startActivity(upIntent);
                }

                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

**Fragment Z code inside activity B:**

```
//Code omitted, basically I get the extra_string from the intent
//(from the a href) and processed it here.
```

**Now, these steps work:**

1. Open app from launcher (hence, activity A is shown).
2. Tap device's recent app button, open chrome, navigate to web that contains that *a href* and click it.
3. App opened activity B, fragment Z can obtain the extra_string
4. Tap device's recent app button, go to chrome, and click *a href* again.
5. App opened activity B, fragment Z can obtain the extra_string.

**BUT, these are the steps that lead to *the problem*:**

1. Swipe app from recent app (this is important).
2. Open chrome, navigate to web that contains the *a href* and click it.
3. The app opened directly to activity B, the fragment Z can obtain the extra_string successfully.
4. Press up, the app "goes back" to activity A successfully.
5. Press device's recent app button, open chrome (back to the web that contains *a href*) and press the *a href* again.

Expectation:

6. The app opened directly to activity B.

Reality:

6. The app opened to activity A.

I really have no idea what's going on here. I have tried to search for similar problem in SO to no avail. Anybody experienced the same problem?